# How to best propagate change notifications upwards a hierarchical structure for binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, hierarchy, inotifypropertychanged, composite

If i have a folder-like structure that uses the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and i bind the root folder to a `TreeView`. It would be quite useful if i can display certain properties that are being accumulated from the folder's contents. The question is, how do i best inform the folder that changes occurred in a child-element so that the accumulative properties get updated?

The context in which i need this is a small RSS-FeedReader i am trying to make. This are the most important objects and aspects of my model:

Composite interface:

```
public interface IFeedComposite : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Title { get; set; }

    int UnreadFeedItemsCount { get; }

    ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems { get; }
}
```

FeedComposite (aka Folder)

```
public class FeedComposite : BindableObject, IFeedComposite
    {
        private string title = "";
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<IFeedComposite> children = new ObservableCollection<IFeedComposite>();
        public ObservableCollection<IFeedComposite> Children
        {
            get { return children; }
            set
            {
                children.Clear();
                foreach (IFeedComposite item in value)
                {
                    children.Add(item);
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Children");
            }
        }

        public FeedComposite() { }

        public FeedComposite(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<FeedItem> feedItems = new ObservableCollection<FeedItem>();
                foreach (IFeedComposite child in Children)
                {
                    foreach (FeedItem item in child.FeedItems)
                    {
                        feedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                return feedItems;
            }
        }


    public int UnreadFeedItemsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (from i in FeedItems
                    where i.IsUnread
                    select i).Count();
        }
    }
```

Feed:

```
public class Feed : BindableObject, IFeedComposite
    {
        private string url = "";
        public string Url
        {
            get { return url; }
            set
            {
                url = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }

        ...


        private ObservableCollection<FeedItem> feedItems = new ObservableCollection<FeedItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems
        {
            get { return feedItems; }
            set
            {
                feedItems.Clear();
                foreach (FeedItem item in value)
                {
                    AddFeedItem(item);
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }

        public int UnreadFeedItemsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return (from i in FeedItems
                        where i.IsUnread
                        select i).Count();
            }
        }

        public Feed() { }

        public Feed(string url)
        {
            Url = url;
        }
```

Ok, so here is the thing, if i bind a `TextBlock.Text` to the `UnreadFeedItemsCount` there won't be simple notifications when an item is marked unread, so one of my approaches has been to handle the `PropertyChanged` event of every `FeedItem` and if the `IsUnread`-Property is changed i have my `Feed` make a notification that the property `UnreadFeedItemsCount` has been changed. With this approach i also need to handle all `PropertyChanged` events of all `Feeds` and `FeedComposites` in `Children` of `FeedComposite`, from the sound of it, it should be obvious that this is not such a very good idea, you need to be very careful that items never get added to or removed from any collection without having attached the `PropertyChanged` event handler first.

Also: What do i do with the `CollectionChanged`-Events which necessarily also cause a change in the sum of the unread items count? Sounds like more event handling fun.

It is such a mess; it would be great if anyone has an elegant solution to this since i do not want the feed-reader to end up as awful as my first attempt years ago when i did not even know about DataBinding...

Answer (score 1):

Well I thought I'd give your question a go, to see what I would come up with. Its untested and its is kinda along the same lines as what you already had. The major difference I made is added methods to handle the add and removal of feeds which handle the event binding needed for it to work. Theres a bit of code so here goes,

I all my code is in a single file, youll need to modify slightly if you want in in separate files.

First the groovy extension method for the PropertyChangedEventHandler
You dont need to use it, but I like it alot.

```
public static class NotifyPropertyChangedExtention
    {
        public static void Raise<T, TP>(this PropertyChangedEventHandler pc, T source, Expression<Func<T, TP>> pe)
        {
            if (pc != null)
            {
                pc.Invoke(source, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(((MemberExpression)pe.Body).Member.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Second the FeedItem minus the feed stuff :) I have a check to raise a change event only when the value actually changes. You can see the Raise extension method in use here, no strings lovely.

```
class FeedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isUnread;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsUnread
    {
        get { return _isUnread; }
        set
        {
            if (_isUnread != value)
            {
                _isUnread = value;
                PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.IsUnread);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Interfaces, I made mine differ slightly, in that my folders can contain other folders as well as feeds.

```
internal interface IFeedComposite : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    int UnreadFeedItemsCount { get; }
}

internal interface IFeedFolder : IFeedComposite
{
    ObservableCollection<IFeedFolder> FeedFolders { get; }
    ObservableCollection<IFeed> Feeds { get; }
    void AddFeed(IFeed newFeed);
    void RemoveFeed(IFeed feedToRemove);
    void AddFeedFolder(IFeedFolder newFeedFolder);
    void RemoveFeedFolder(IFeedFolder feedFolderToRemove);
}

internal interface IFeed : IFeedComposite
{
    ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems { get; }
    void AddFeedItem(FeedItem newFeedItem);
    void RemoveFeedItem(FeedItem feedItemToRemove);
}
```

Now the Feed Class, the AddFeedItem method hooks the property changed event for you, and if it is marked as unread, raises the property changed event for the count. You could overload this method, to accept a list of items, then once they have been added to the list, if any where unread, raise a single property changed event for them all.

```
class Feed : IFeed
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<FeedItem> _feedItems = new ObservableCollection<FeedItem>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UnreadFeedItemsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (from i in FeedItems
                    where i.IsUnread
                    select i).Count();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems
    {
        get { return _feedItems; }
    }

    public void AddFeedItem(FeedItem newFeed)
    {
        newFeed.PropertyChanged += NewFeedPropertyChanged;
        _feedItems.Add(newFeed);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.FeedItems);
        if (newFeed.IsUnread)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFeedItem(FeedItem feedToRemove)
    {
        _feedItems.Remove(feedToRemove);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.FeedItems);
        if (feedToRemove.IsUnread)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    void NewFeedPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsUnread")
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the FeedFolder class, much the same as the feed class but this one can hold a list of feeds and a list of feed folders (which hold their own feeds). You can easily add a method or property to return all feeditems from feeds and feedfolders if you need. Again, various checks to only raise change events if needed.

```
class FeedFolder : IFeedFolder
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<IFeedFolder> _feedFolders = new ObservableCollection<IFeedFolder>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<IFeed> _feeds = new ObservableCollection<IFeed>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UnreadFeedItemsCount
    {
        get { return Feeds.Sum(x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount) + FeedFolders.Sum(x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IFeedFolder> FeedFolders
    {
        get { return _feedFolders; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IFeed> Feeds
    {
        get { return _feeds; }
    }

    public void AddFeed(IFeed newFeed)
    {
        newFeed.PropertyChanged += NewFeedPropertyChanged;
        _feeds.Add(newFeed);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.Feeds);
        if (newFeed.UnreadFeedItemsCount > 0)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    void NewFeedPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "UnreadFeedItemsCount")
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFeed(IFeed feedToRemove)
    {
        _feeds.Remove(feedToRemove);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.Feeds);
        if (feedToRemove.UnreadFeedItemsCount > 0)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    public void AddFeedFolder(IFeedFolder newFeedFolder)
    {
        newFeedFolder.PropertyChanged += NewFeedPropertyChanged;
        _feedFolders.Add(newFeedFolder);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.FeedFolders);
        if (newFeedFolder.UnreadFeedItemsCount > 0)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveFeedFolder(IFeedFolder feedFolderToRemove)
    {
        _feedFolders.Remove(feedFolderToRemove);
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.FeedFolders);
        if (feedFolderToRemove.UnreadFeedItemsCount > 0)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.UnreadFeedItemsCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Now for usage, remember I havent tested this, but it should be mostly right.

```
var myFolder = new FeedFolder();
var myFeed = new Feed();
var myFeedItem = new FeedItem();
myFeedItem.IsUnread = true;
myFeed.AddFeedItem(myFeedItem);
myFolder.AddFeed(myFeed);

var mySecondFeedItem = new FeedItem();

//add a second feeditem to feed, but it is marked as read, so no notifications raised for unread count.
myFeed.AddFeedItem(mySecondFeedItem);

//this should fire off change events all the way up to the folder
mySecondFeedItem.IsUnread = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you went to quite some lengths here. Right now i cannot give you a longer response, i'll try to do so as soon as i can...

Comment: There are some things i don't like about your answer, you created two more interfaces that seem rather useless since the probability that any other object besides the existing ones will even implement them is very low. You also pretty much obliterated the composite pattern by splitting up the Children of FeedComposite into Folders an feeds, thereby making no use of the IFeedComposite interface, you have many methods that are practically identical and could be replaced by one, the split also makes the binding more troublesome and you cannot have a mixed order of feeds and folders.

Comment: My original solution had the same helper methods that add handlers when adding an object to a collection, but as i noted in the question it'd be great to hear other suggestions that might be better. There are some things in your answer that are helpful like the extension method which looks rather handy, so thank you for the effort.